# How to handle String to Double conversion?

Tags: swift, string, double

I've problem with conversion from String to Double. While converting it returns strange value. I have it in my big calc App but I simplified it into this inside playground.

```
var nineNine : String = "9.9" 
var nineEight : String = "9.8"

var firstNumber = Double(nineNine) as! Double // Returns 9.9
var secondNumber = Double(nineEight) as! Double // Returns 9.8000000001
```

I expect the output of 9.8 and it's 9.8000000001 
The problem is the second number. Any ideas how to fix it? :)

Comment: [Is floating point math broken?](//stackoverflow.com/q/588004)

Comment: if you need precision use `Decimal` type

Comment: @JohnnyMopp thank you, I'll try to come around then :)

Comment: `if let decimal = Decimal(string: nineEight) {`

Comment: @LeoDabus thank you, how about multiplying Decimals. Do I have to Use NSDecimalNumber ?

Comment: You just need to unwrap optional `let nineNine  = "9.9"
let nineEight  = "9.8"



let decimal1 = Decimal(string: nineNine)!
let decimal2 = Decimal(string: nineEight)!
decimal1 * decimal2` // 97.02

Comment: @LeoDabus yes, Im stupid. With force unwrapping works well :) Thank you once again.

Comment: If you are sure the string is valid just force unwrap otherwise use `if let` or `??` nil coalescing operator

Answer (score 0):

1 - if you want to convert String to Double with 2 decimal values and change the double value with 2 decimal. Try this code

```
 /// String to Double
 let yourValue = "9.8"
 let formatter = NumberFormatter()
 formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
 if let myInteger = Double(yourValue) {
    let myNumber = NSNumber(value: myInteger)
    let secondNumber = currencyFormatter.string(from: myNumber)
 }
// result = 9.80
```